# Capture Still Image fails when Image Data Sample is used to render OpenGL texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, avfoundation

I have to capture a bunch of images using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:` and render them on screen using **OpenGL** as textures, for which I pass the *CVPixelBufferRef* from *CMSampleBufferRef* of the capture output. The first capture happens successfully, but for subsequent captures I get error

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11801 "Cannot Complete Action"`

The code will be as follows.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (self.videoConnection) {
        [self.imageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:self.videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
            if (!imageDataSampleBuffer) {
                return ;
            }
            if (imageDataSampleBuffer) {
                CVPixelBufferRef pxBuff = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageDataSampleBuffer);
                if ([self.captureDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didCaptureBufferRef:)]) {
                    [_captureDelegate didCaptureBufferRef:pxBuff];
                }
            }
        }];
    }});
```

And

```
didCaptureBufferRef:
```

eventually calls this function (i have skipped the intermediate calls since **pxBuff** is not used anywhere but just passed on)

```
- (void)textureFromBufferRef:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

CVReturn err  = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCacheRef, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RED_EXT, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, GL_RED_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &_captureImageTextureRef);
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(_captureImageTextureRef), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_captureImageTextureRef));
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? When I remove

```
[_captureDelegate didCaptureBufferRef:pxBuff];
```

things works fine and captures happen successfully.

Comment: what's happening inside of `[_captureDelegate didCaptureBufferRef:pxBuff];`?

Comment: @SAKrisT, sorry for the delay (had to travel an hour to get home). I have added the def. for function that uses CVPixelBufferRef. Thanks.